# Passing multiple values in angularjs from checkbox input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aem, aem-6

How do I pass multiple values for a multiselect checkbox's checked values:

My multiselect dropdown should list only RewardCode in the dropdown, but I have to pass all others back to angular as json when that checkbox is checked, but as of now I could only do pass one value:

My json:

```
{
    "Reward": [{
        "RewardType": 1,
        "RewardTypeValue": "PartCodes",
        "RewardCode": "CB_USD_20_US",
        "DiscountValue": 20.0
    },
    {
        "RewardType": 1,
        "RewardTypeValue": "PartCodes",
        "RewardCode": "CB_USD_30_US",
        "DiscountValue": 30.0
    },
    {
        "RewardType": 1,
        "RewardTypeValue": "PartCodes",
        "RewardCode": "CB_USD_40_US",
        "DiscountValue": 40.0
    },
    {
        "RewardType": 1,
        "RewardTypeValue": "PartCodes",
        "RewardCode": "CB_USD_50_US",
        "DiscountValue": 50.0
    }]

}
```

Html code:

```
<li ng-repeat="reward in RewardsList ">
           <input id="{{reward.RewardCode}}.{{reward.RewardType}}"
                  type="checkbox"
                  ng-checked="selection.indexOf(reward.RewardCode) > -1"
                  ng-click="toggleSelection(reward.RewardCode)"
                  value="{{reward.RewardCode}}" /> 
    <label  for="{{reward.RewardCode}}">{{reward.RewardCode}}</label>
    </li>
```

Angular Code:

```
$scope.rewards = [];
$scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(selectedRewards) {
   var idx = $scope.rewards.indexOf(selectedRewards);
   console.log(selectedRewards);

   // is currently selected
   if (idx > -1) {
     $scope.rewards.splice(idx, 1);
   }

   // is newly selected
   else {
     $scope.rewards.push(selectedRewards);
   }
   console.log($scope.rewards);
};
```

Comment: 1:) You can simply use "ng-model" instead of "ng-checked" for "toggleSelection" method. 2:) what do want to pass back to angular? Other properties of the selected Reward Or the other Rewards?

Comment: For each checkboxes which are selected, I want to pass Reward.RewardCode, Reward.RewardType and Reward.DiscountValue back to angular as a json.